# Wordpress : Child-theme CSS weird behavior

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently customizing a wordpress theme.

Here my case, through a widget, I generate a div which has several classes :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 focus-box item-1">...</div>
```

The parent theme and bootstrap stylesheet already apply respectively properties on focus-box and col-lg-3 classes.

Well, I added to my child-theme stylesheet (which works well for many others things) this :

```
.item-1 { background-color: orange; }
```

And this does not work... nothing happen but I tried to do this in my child-theme CSS :

```
.col-lg-3 (or focus-box) { background-color: orange; }
.item-1 { background-color: orange; }
```

This way works... I really don't understand anything to what is happening here.

My Child-theme stylesheet is the last one to be load, so It should override all others, isn't it ?

If anyone has a clue, I would appreciate to get it :-)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally overcame this issue by reviewing my style sheet loading priority and so on.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

First, I already tried to use `!important` it didn't work, it was the same using stronger selector.

I know how to inspect code with my browser, and that's why I told you that my child-theme css was the last one to be loaded because I checked it.

The thing really weird, according to me, is that the result is different if I put `col-lg-3` in my stylesheet or not.

I have similar issues with others HTML elements in my code.

To sum up :

- My Child-Theme CSS is loaded after the parent-one
- I checked it in my browser development tool
- I also notice that the place where my CSS properties is change the result, if I put it at the end of my child-theme css it sometimes work example :

{

```
/* IF I PUT THE SELECTOR .focus-box .service-icon here It doesn't work */
/* SEE THE LAST ELEMENT BELOW */

.focus-box:nth-child(4n+1) .service-icon:hover {
    border: 5px solid #e96656;
}

.focus-box:nth-child(4n+2) .service-icon:hover{
    border: 5px solid #34d293;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+3) .service-icon:hover {
    border: 5px solid #3ab0e2;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+4) .service-icon:hover{
    border: 5px solid #f7d861;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+1) .red-border-bottom:before {
    background: #e96656;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+2) .red-border-bottom:before {
    background: #34d293;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+3) .red-border-bottom:before {
    background: #3ab0e2;
}
.focus-box:nth-child(4n+4) .red-border-bottom:before {
    background: #f7d861;
}
.focus-box h5 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #404040;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(224,82,6,0.2);
}

.other-focuses {
    background: url(images/lines.png) repeat-x center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.other-focuses .section-footer-title {
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #404040;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.other-focus-list {
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -17px;
}
.other-focus-list ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.other-focus-list ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.other-focus-list ul li i {
    margin-right: 8px;
}


.item-dashboard {

    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

}

.focus-box p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;

}

/* IF I PUT IT THERE THEN IT WORKS */
.focus-box .service-icon {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0px solid #ececec;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Focus Box HTML Code :

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 focus-box item-dashboard" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0.15s over 1s">

        <div class="service-icon">


                <a href="#">
                    <i class="pixeden" style="background:url(#/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cle_main_2.png) no-repeat center;width:100%; height:100%;"></i> <!-- FOCUS ICON-->
                </a>



        </div>

        <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->



    </div>
```

The question is why my child-theme CSS doesn't correctly override the parent one ? Why the place of my css element affect the result (I know the place affect if you override a property, but here it doesn't look like this...)

Thansk again for you help.

Comment: I just added it in my last answer :-)